# Showing xml as json, issues with spacing (xslt)

Tags: json, xml, xslt

I have a series of XML documents which I need to diplay with the following format,
[image]

Currently I'm working on this xlst and doing the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/eventos">
<html>
<body>
    {
        <br/>
        "fecha": "<xsl:value-of select="fecha"/>",
        <br/>
        eventos: [{
        <xsl:for-each select="evento">
            "evento":{
                "titulo" : "<xsl:value-of select="titulo"/>",<br/>
                "descripcion" : "<xsl:value-of select="descripcion"/>",<br/>
                "lugar" : {
                    <xsl:element name="lugar"/>
                    "nombre" : "<xsl:value-of select="nombre"/>"

                }
                "hora" : "<xsl:value-of select="hora"/>",},

                <br/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    }]
    }
</body>

</html>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, I can't seem to get the spacing right:

- How could I indent the elements?
- Is there a way to get line breaks without using the `br` tag? At the moment, when I press F12 on my browser, I see the line breaks, while I'd like the whole document to be in one piece (tag?).

Thanks!

Comment: can you add your input

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you want to display JSON as nicely formatted HTML. Have you thought about using `<pre>` element of HTML instead?